# Is it possible to do a user search by taxonomy?

Tags: 7, views, search

my question is because I have users with a taxonomy field and what I want to do is search for those taxonomies.

Example: a user in his profile chose a taxonomy, let's say soccer.
I want to make a search engine in which users search for soccer and all users who have a soccer taxonomy appear.

I do not know any module for this and I do not know if it is possible to do it with a view.

•Drupal 7
•Views 7.x-3.20

Any help?

Comment: Did you even try to make a View?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a "User" View

[image]

2. Add a "Filter Criteria" with your taxonomy field

   - Click "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"
3. Done.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfect. I wanted to ask you if there is any way to add more criteria in that exposed filter using the same field, I mean that users can search by taxonomy, by name or search some content in the same exposed filter field.

thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. It's possible. I would play around with a global combined filter.

Comment: Ok if you can do it, I'd appreciate it if you could help me, I'm trying but I still can not find the solution. Thank you.